# Convert a string into iso date format

Tags: java, datetime, string-formatting, jodatime, iso

So I am trying to convert a string into an iso format for the date.
This is the string that I am trying to convert "2016-07-05 02:14:35.0"
I would like to have it in this format the iso 8601
"2016-07-05T02:14:35.0"

I have this so far

```
 DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm:sszzz");
     new LocalDate();
    LocalDate newDate = LocalDate.parse(created,format);
     created = newDate.toString();
```

But it is giving me this exception

```
ERROR: Illegal pattern component: T; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Illegal pattern component: T
```

I followed the examples and I don't know what I am doing wrong here.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: See: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/time/format/DateTimeFormatter.html#ISO_INSTANT. If that doesn't help you use change the pattern to `YYYY-MM-DD'THH:mm:sszzz`

Comment: Overthinking the problem? `"2016-07-05 02:14:35.0".replace( " " , "T" )`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Firstly, that value is a `LocalDateTime`, *not* a `LocalDate`. If you want to get a date out in the end, I'd convert it to a `LocalDateTime` first, then take the date part of that.

When performing date formatting and parsing, always read the documentation *really carefully*. It looks like you're using Joda Time (due to using `forPattern`; if you can move to Java 8 that would be beneficial). That means you should be reading the [`DateTimeFormat` docs](http://www.joda.org/joda-time/apidocs/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html).

Current problems with your pattern:

- You're using 'D' instead of 'd'; that means day-of-year
- You've specified 'T' without quoting it, and it isn't in the pattern anyway
- You've ignored the fraction-of-second part of your value
- You've specified 'zz' when there's no time zone indicator in the value.

Here's a working example:

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2016-07-05 02:14:35.0";
        DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(text, format);
        System.out.println(localDateTime);
    }
}
```

If you *actually* want to parse values with `T` in the middle, you'd use a pattern of `"yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S"` - note how then the `T` is quoted so it's treated literally instead of as a format specifier.

Note that this is *just* parsing. It's not "converting a string into ISO date format" - it's converting a string into a `LocalDateTime`. If you then want to *format* that value in an ISO format, you need to be using `DateTimeFormatter.print`, with an appropriate format. For example, you might want to convert to a format of `yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S`':

```
import org.joda.time.*;
import org.joda.time.format.*;

public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String text = "2016-07-05 02:14:35.0";
        DateTimeFormatter parser = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.S");
        LocalDateTime localDateTime = LocalDateTime.parse(text, parser);
        DateTimeFormatter printer = DateTimeFormat.forPattern("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss.S");
        String formatted = printer.print(localDateTime);
        System.out.println(formatted); // Output 2016-07-05T02:14:35.0
    }
}
```

The code above will only handle a single digit fraction-of-second. You could parse using `.SSS` instead of `.S`, but you really need to work out what you want the output to be in different cases (e.g. for 100 milliseconds, do you want .1 or .100?).

Comment: But the value I want does not have a T in it. I thought that there was a way to put the T in automatically.

Comment: @MNM: But the value you're *parsing* doesn't. You haven't shown us what result you want. If you need to convert to a different format, you need two different formatters. It would help if you'd provide the expected output...

Comment: I want the iso format so like this yyyy MM dd T HH mm ss  The T is what I want to put in there. I don't want to break apart the original string and then add a T in there and then concat all that together

Comment: @MNM: And what about the fractional seconds? And what about separators? (Hyphens, dashes, spaces...) Basically you should edit your question to be a *lot* clearer about this.

Comment: @MNM: See my edited answer for more details of how to do this, but it's hard to help with only partial information.

Answer (score 2):

You have some errors in your code:

- The pattern should be 'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS'. Be aware of upper-
  and lowercase.
- Use LocalDateTime to get date and time. LocalDate only holds the date.

The corrected code:

```
String created = "2016-07-05 02:14:35.000";
DateTimeFormatter format = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss.SSS");
LocalDateTime newDate = LocalDateTime.parse(created,format);
created = newDate.toString();
System.out.println(created);
```

Answer (score -4):

Use the following format to convert

```
     String format = "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss"
```

You are using the wrong format to convert. Using T is only to separate the date from time.
Use the format like this

```
     String = "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss"
```

Comment: "yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ss" use the this

Comment: This is *still* incorrect - it doesn't include the fraction of a second, the first pattern you present still uses minutes instead of months and 12-hour hours, and the second snippet you present wouldn't even compile.